# Cursor doesn't disappear in fullscreen

Tags: fullscreen

when watching videos in Firefox or Chromium in full-screen, the mouse-pointer is always visible (Ubuntu 21.10)

Comment: In my system (21.10), YouTube on Firefox does not exhibit this problem: The mouse pointer disappears after a few seconds.

Comment: this is in in my system for youtube also - but when i use the PiP Feature and then Fullscreen the pointer wont disappear. But in the german ARD Mediathek for example the pointer won't disappear for the "normal" fullscreen too. https://www.sportschau.de/olympia/videostream---die-olympischen-winterspiele-in-peking--ab--uhr-108.html

Comment: I noticed this started a few months ago on most streaming sites. I use Chrome.

Comment: by the way - with chromium i have the same problem